# Jacoco is not cover elvis operator test coverage in kotlin android project

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit, jacoco

[image]

Not able to generate test coverage for Elvis operator. I was used jacoco and kover.

Comment: Are you testing all the various nulls? In other words, `dataSyncResponse`, `dataSyncResponse.userpreferences`, `dataSyncResponse.userpreferences.tutorialCompleted` :-)

Comment: @karllindmark Yes basically this is an interface function, I am using the Elvis operator for null safety.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your mouse over the yellow highlight, Jacoco report would indicate how many branches are missed in code coverage. Your test is just hitting some cases.

Basically, jacoco sees your code like below.

```kotlin
// dataSyncResponse?.userpreferences?.tutorialCompleted?:""

if (dataSyncResponse != null) {
    if (dataSyncResponse.userpreferences != null) {
        return dataSyncResponse.userpreferences.tutorialCompleted
    }
}

return ""
```

Did your test have provided a test case for

- null dataSyncResponse
- non null dataSyncResponse,

  - null userpreferences
  - non null userpreferences

    - null tutorialCompleted
    - non null tutorialCompleted

Comment: I know it's a little dated, but what if tutorialCompleted cannot be null? I have the same issue but I can't test that case and somehow jacoco doesn't give me 100% branch coverage

Comment: @tagtraeumer I think Jacoco creates coverage report from Java bytecode not from source code written in java, kotlin ... If your goal is 100% branch coverage, you can either add a small java test code where `tutorialCompleted` is null or use java reflection to nullify the `tutorialCompleted`.

Comment: thanks for that, I will have a look into it!